# Understanding Arrays of Arrays

Tags: perl

I'm going through the documentation of perldsc in the section of Array of Arrays and it shows what an Array of Arrays looks like

```
@AoA = (
    [ "fred", "barney" ],
    [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
    [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
  );
```

In the next section on lines 1 - 4 it shows how to generate one

```
# reading from file
  while ( <> ) {
 push @AoA, [ split ];
}
```

I want to learn how to create one. I created a file and had the following contents in it.

> John Adam Joe
>
> Rod Fred James
>
> Allison Frank Jean

Then I used the code from the example to create an Array of Arrays

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my @AoA;

while ( <> ) {
 push @AoA, [ split ];
 }

print Dumper(@AoA);
```

When I ran the code, the contents of Dumper is

```
$VAR1 = [
      'John',
      'Adam',
      'Joe'
    ];
$VAR2 = [
      'Rod',
      'Fred',
      'James'
    ];
$VAR3 = [
      'Allison',
      'Frank',
      'Jean'
    ];
```

As I can see, it printed 3  arrays, I thought it should print an array of arrays.

But I when ran the same code with a small modification

```
print Dumper(\@AoA);
```

It printed.

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'John',
        'Adam',
        'Joe'
      ],
      [
        'Rod',
        'Fred',
        'James'
      ],
      [
        'Allison',
        'Frank',
        'Jean'
      ]
    ];
```

Which is an Array of Arrays.

Here is my understanding of \@AoA. This is a pointer to the memory location of @AoA. So please clarify why I had to use \@AoA to get the output that is expected?

***UPDATE***

I think my confusion is clearly explained in perlreftut

> One of the most important new features in Perl 5 was the capability to manage complicated data structures like multidimensional arrays and nested hashes. To enable these, Perl 5 introduced a feature called references, and using references is the key to managing complicated, structured data in Perl.
>
> References in Perl are like names for arrays and hashes. They're Perl's private, internal names, so you can be sure they're unambiguous. Unlike "Barack Obama", a reference only refers to one thing, and you always know what it refers to. If you have a reference to an array, you can recover the entire array from it. If you have a reference to a hash, you can recover the entire hash. But the reference is still an easy, compact scalar value.
>   You can't have a hash whose values are arrays; hash values can only be scalars. We're stuck with that. But a single reference can refer to an entire array, and references are scalars, so you can have a hash of references to arrays, and it'll act a lot like a hash of arrays, and it'll be just as useful as a hash of arrays.

Comment: `print Dumper(@AoA);` prints list of arrays (same as `Dumper($AoA[0],$AoA[1], ..))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is just due to how variables are passed to Perl subroutines.**

A `sub` takes a list of variables, of any length, as its arguments.  If you call a sub with an array as the argument, all the array elements get passed in to the sub.

So

```
my @array = (1,2,3);

foo(@array);
```

Is no different than this from the sub's perspective:

```
my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;
my $c = 3;

foo($a,$b,$c);
```

If you call `Dumper()` with any array, you will simply get the list of array elements.  It won't "see" the array itself unless you pass it in as a reference.

Comment: So why in Perl do I have to pass it as a reference to see the Arrays of Arrays?

Comment: @BioRod Because an array cannot be passed around. It's not an object like in other languages. Think of an array like a list with a name on it. But when you give the list to someone else, they cannot see the name. So when you use an array as the argument to a function, that function will just see the list of elements. But if you create a reference, you get **one thing**. The reference is a scalar value. It's only a pointer to the memory address that holds your array. Behind that address, there's your array. Then `Dumper` can make that reference to an array visible.